# Can't cover lines inside a React/Typescript try catch with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following code in React/TypeScript:

```
  const logUser = async () => {
    console.log(`Logging: ${email} - ${password}`);
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/auth`,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept-Language": localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng"),
        },
        data: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
      });

      const user = buildUserData(res.data.data);
      saveUserData(user.name, user.email, user.roles, user.token);
      setDismissAlert(true);
      console.log(res.data);
      login().then(() => navigate("/dashboard/overview"));
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err.response?.data.otp) {
        navigate("/otp", { state: { email: email, password: password } });
      } else if (err.data?.data.message) {
        setLoginError(err.data?.data.message);
        setDismissAlert(false);
      } else {
        setLoginError(t("login.validation.loginError"));
        setDismissAlert(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

In my tests, besides the axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(); returns what is expected with the sucessful request, the lines below just don't get covered:

```
    const user = buildUserData(res.data.data);
    saveUserData(user.name, user.email, user.roles, user.token);
    setDismissAlert(true);
    console.log(res.data);
    login().then(() => navigate("/dashboard/overview"));
```

I tried to return a mock data in this way:

```
    const mockResponse = {
       data: {
         user: {
           id: 1,
           name: "user",
           email: "user@mail.com",
           email_verified_at: null,
           created_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:23.000000Z",
           updated_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:29.000000Z",
           deleted_at: null,
           last_login_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:29.301355Z",
           roles: ["user"],
         },
         token: {
           access_token: "1|Buc8kgCTGFzHdS2HU11ZmWS30SEXHEiLCEQGbBnH",
           token_type: "Bearer",
         },
       },
     };
```

And in my tests:

```
axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResponse);
```

But this won't solve the uncovered lines.

Here is the coverage report:

[image]

What do I need to do to cover the lines after the axios request inside the try block (not catch)?

Comment: You might wanna check  working of ```buildUserData```  callback and log ```res.data.data``` while testing. It might be skipping  to ```catch``` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - instead of using this API:

```js
const res = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/auth`,
```

use this:

```js
const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/auth`, {...
```

Then in your tests:

```js
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");

it('some test', async () => {
   axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResponse);
   // here your test
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach but the lines keep uncovered...

Answer (score 0):

Your coverage report screenshot shows that the execution goes to the `catch` > `else` block.

As pointed out by MallikarjunMG in the question comments, it is very likely that your `buildUserData(res.data.data)` expression throws an error.

Jest [`mockResolvedValueOnce`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue) returns a resolved Promise with the given value, in your case `mockResponse`, which *does not have* a `data.data` value. Therefore very probably `buildUserData` is called with `undefined` value, but is unable to handle it, hence it throws an exception and your code jumps to the `catch` block.

Depending on the shape of your actual response payload:

- if it does have `data` value, it will indeed be accessible in [axios `result.data.data`](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema), therefore you have to adjust your `mockResponse` to match that shape:

```
const mockResponse = {
  data: { // Axios response payload
       data: { // your API response shape
         user: {
           id: 1,
           // etc.
         },
         token: {
           // etc.
         },
       },
  }
};
```

- if it does not have a `data` property (directly an object with `user` and `token` in your case), then you just need to call `buildUserData(res.data)`

To inspect your actual API response, you could directly log it, use the [Developer Tools network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/), or use another client like Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly mock axios

```js
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');
```

Then in your test mock the return value of axios.

```js
const mockResponse = {
 data: {
   user: {
     id: 1,
     name: "user",
     email: "user@mail.com",
     email_verified_at: null,
     created_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:23.000000Z",
     updated_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:29.000000Z",
     deleted_at: null,
     last_login_at: "2022-12-27T17:10:29.301355Z",
     roles: ["user"],
   },
   token: {
     access_token: "1|Buc8kgCTGFzHdS2HU11ZmWS30SEXHEiLCEQGbBnH",
     token_type: "Bearer",
   },
 },
};


test('test', async () => {
  axios.mockReturnValue(() => Promise.resolve({ 
    data: mockResponse
  }))
})
```